# Defining generated clock as synchronous in RTL simulation

Tags: system-verilog

I am generating a divided clock, something like this:

```
logic div_clk;
always_ff @(posedge clk or negedge rstb) begin 
   if(!rstb) div_clk <= 1'b0;
   else div_clk <= !div_clk;
end
```

I then launch data on `clk` and capture on `div_clk`. Something like this:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin 
   clk_data <= something;
end

always_ff @(posedge div_clk) begin 
   div_clk_data <= clk_data;
end
```

In my simulations I am getting a race condition since `clk_data` updates coincident with `div_clk` and the `div_clk_data` gets the wrong value.

In synthesis I define these two clocks to be synchronous by creating a generated clock:

```
create_clock -name CLK [get_ports clk]
create_generated_clock -name GEN_DIV_CLK -source [get_ports clk] -divide_by 2 [get_pins div_clk]
```

Is there something equivalent that I can put into my RTL, or something I can do to tell my simulator that `div_clk` is synchronous to `clk` and prevent the race condition from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where NBA's should not be used. You should not have any NBA's in your clock tree (including gated clocks) if you want the clocks to remain synchronous.